# Javascript comparison between string and number

Tags: javascript

Hi I'm just going over some basic javascript and I came across this piece of code

```
if('3'!=3)
{
   document.write("Hello");
}
```

This writes hello to the screen, however when I change it to:

```
if('3'==3)
{
   document.write("Hello");
}
```

This also writes Hello to the screen

Does anyone know any reason for this? I read that javascript converts a string to a number in a comparison I just dont understand the different behavior when I change the condition

Thanks !!

Comment: The first *doesn't* write hello to the screen.

Comment: cannot reproduce. `3 != '3'` evaluates to `false` for me.

Comment: yes, since 3 == '3' it makes sense :p

Comment: win7, chrome16: `if('3'!=3)
{
   Alert("...");/*Never Entered*/
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do a strict comparison  use the `===` operator or `!==`

Answer (score 3):

This happens because the `==` operator tries to convert both operands to the same type before comparing. In other words, it sees that the string `'3'` is the same as the number `3`, and says that they're equal. Use the `===` operator to avoid this, as it doesn't attempt to convert the operands (it performs a **strict** equality check).

This *won't* write "Hello":

```
if('3'===3)
{
   document.write("Hello");
}
```

Here's another interesting example:

```
if(false == 0) {
    document.write("Hello");
}
```

It will write hello! This is because `0` is seen as a value that can be converted to `false`. As before, using the `===` operator will solve this:

```
if(false === 0) {
    document.write("Hello"); // won't write hello
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this is because == doesn't care about type.

use === instead.

Comment: As well, the most shocking example for me is the famous comparison with false, 0, "0" and undefined. ALL are "==" but ofcourse none are actually "==="